# How to solve an infinite series given some terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that $a_0 = -3, a_1 = 5, a_2 = -4, a_3 = 2$, and $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k = 7$, how can $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ be found?

It doesn't make much sense to me that there is enough information here to solve the problem.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} =a_1 + a_2 +a_3+\cdots$; $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} = a_2+a_3+\cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if $ a_4=9$ and

$$a_5=a_6=a_7=...=0$$

then

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k=$$
$$a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+...=7$$
and

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=$$
$$a_1+a_2+...=5+7=12$$